# Cloned Custom HTML Element does not become custom element until it's attached to the main DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, custom-element

Consider the following scenario where I have a list of custom elements which is dynamically created. The `CustomElement` has a custom property `displayName` that should do something when set:

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  set displayName(v) {
    this.querySelector(".name").textContent = v;
  }
}
customElements.define("custom-element", CustomElement)

const template = document.querySelector("template");
const list = document.querySelector(".list");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const customElTemplate = template.content.firstElementChild;
  console.log("Template constructor: ", customElTemplate.constructor.name);

  const el = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  console.log("Cloned el constructor:", el.constructor.name);
  
  el.displayName = "Should has content";
  
  const frag = new DocumentFragment();
  frag.appendChild(el);
  console.log("Cloned el in DocumentFragment constructor:", el.constructor.name);
  
  list.appendChild(frag);
  console.log("Cloned el in Document constructor:", el.constructor.name);
});
```

```css
custom-element {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <custom-element><span class="name"></span></custom-element>
</template>

<button>Add Item</button>

<div class="list"></div>
```

When clicking the button, the console output are:

```
Template constructor:  HTMLElement
Cloned el constructor: HTMLElement
Cloned el in DocumentFragment constructor: HTMLElement
Cloned el in Document constructor: CustomElement
```

As you can see, the cloned element doesn't become `CustomElement` until it's attached to the root document and `displayName` is simply a plain property that does nothing.

`el.displayName = "Should has content";` won't work even after attaching to a `DocumentFragment`. It only works after attaching to the document (i.e. after `list.appendChild(frag);` in the above example)

Why is this happening? Is there anyway I can set up the element before attaching it to the main document?

UPDATE: I see there is [`customElements.upgrade`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/upgrade), but even adding it, nothing is changed, unlike the example provided in the article:

```js
customElements.upgrade(el);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out about [`customElements.upgrade`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/upgrade). Turned out I have to call it **after** attaching to a **shadow DOM**:

```js
frag.appendChild(el);
customElements.upgrade(el);

// Now el is CustomElement
console.log(el.constructor.name);
```

> The upgrade() method of the CustomElementRegistry interface upgrades all *shadow-containing custom elements* in a Node subtree, even before they are connected to the main document.

For the example in my question, I need to:

- Attach it to a `DocumentFragment`,
- Call `customElements.upgrade`
- Now I can use custom behavior like setting `displayName`.

Working code:

```js
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  set displayName(v) {
    this.querySelector(".name").textContent = v;
  }
}
customElements.define("custom-element", CustomElement)

const template = document.querySelector("template");
const list = document.querySelector(".list");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const customElTemplate = template.content.firstElementChild;
  console.log("Template constructor: ", customElTemplate.constructor.name);

  const el = template.content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
  console.log("Cloned el constructor:", el.constructor.name);
  
  const frag = new DocumentFragment();
  frag.appendChild(el);
  customElements.upgrade(el);
  console.log("Cloned el in DocumentFragment constructor:", el.constructor.name);
  
  el.displayName = "Should has content";
  
  list.appendChild(frag);
  console.log("Cloned el in Document constructor:", el.constructor.name);
});
```

```css
custom-element {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <custom-element><span class="name"></span></custom-element>
</template>

<button>Add Item</button>

<div class="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DOM operations can only be done when the (Custom) Element is **in** the DOM

Note: I am saying DOM, not shadowDOM. There is no shadowDOM at all in your code.

Why the `template.content.firstElementChild` to select/create your Custom Element?
That makes `<template>` a very expensive container.

`document.createElement('custom-element')` will create a Custom Element (but it is still not a DOM Element at this point, only the `constructor` will run)

I don't know your use-case; but your code could be condensed to:

```html
<button>Add Item</button>

<div class="list"></div>

<script>
  customElements.define("custom-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<span class="name"></span>`;
    }
    set displayName(v) {
      this.querySelector(".name").textContent = v;
    }
  })

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let newElement = document.createElement("custom-element");
    document.querySelector(".list").append(newElement);
    newElement.displayName = "Should have content";
  });
</script>

<style>
  custom-element {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

If you do need that `<template>`, because you want your HTML in the HTML file:

```html
<template id="CUSTOM-ELEMENT">
  <span class="name"></span>
</template>
<button>Add Item</button>

<div class="list"></div>

<script>
  customElements.define("custom-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
    }
    set displayName(v) {
      this.querySelector(".name").textContent = v;
    }
  })

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let newElement = document.createElement("custom-element");
    document.querySelector(".list").append(newElement);
    newElement.displayName = "Should have content";
  });
</script>

<style>
  custom-element {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

Note: the use of [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append). Often more powerful, because it can append multiple elements.
Append was not available in IE11.

`appendChild` is for when you need its return value.
So you could write:

```js
      document
       .querySelector("button")
       .addEventListener("click", () => 
           document
              .querySelector(".list")
              .appendChild(document.createElement("custom-element"))
              .displayName = "Should have content");
```

Comment: In your example, it's unfortunate that you have to append the element into the DOM before you can do anything with it (custom behaviors). In reality it would not be optimized, for example you need `DocumentFragment` when inserting a lot of items, or you simply want to set things up *before* it is in the DOM (i.e. showing async content). I like your notes though, very helpful and I didn't know before

Comment: Also while you are correct about my example not really have a shadow DOM, technically I believe `DocumentFragment` *may be* a shadow DOM (it acts *similar to* one if you inspect it).